# Java Character vs char: what about memory usage?

Tags: java, performance, memory

In one of my classes I have a field of type `Character`. I preferred it over `char` because sometimes the field has "no value" and `null` seams to me the cleanest way to represent this (lack of) information.

However I'm wondering about the memory footprint of this approach. I'm dealing with hundred of thousands of objects and the negligible difference between the two options may now deserve some investigation.

My first bet is that a `char` takes two bytes whereas a `Character` is an object, and so it takes much more in order to support its life cycle. But I know boxed primitives like `Integer`, `Character` and so on are not ordinary classes (think about boxing and unboxing), so I wonder if the JVM can make some kind of optimization under the hood.

Furthermore, are `Character`s garbage collected like the other stuff or have a different life cycle? Are they pooled from a shared repository? Is this standard or JVM implementation-dependent?

I wasn't able to find any clear information on the Internet about this issue. Can you point me to some information?

Comment: `\0` can be used as a *no-value* char

Comment: Sure, I know about this. :) Given the application domain I can even use ~, # or a Chinese character, but this is not the point

Comment: primitives are always faster then Objects as well as get less memory as all of us know that we prefer char array upon String.(as array in java itself a object but its a debatable issue :D)

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-codetoheap/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are you using `Character`  to create character then prefer to use

```
Character.valueOf('c'); // it returns cached value for 'c' 

Character c = new Character('c');// prefer to avoid
```

Following is an excerpt from javadoc.

> If a new Character instance is not required, this method `Character.valueOf()` should generally be used in preference to the constructor `Character(char)`, as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values.

Comment: Actually, I create it implicitly by boxing.

Comment: @gd1 boxing will use cached values if available.

Comment: You'd need to check it with javap for `Character`, but for `Integer` `valueOf` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Use `int` instead. Use `-1` to represent "no char".

Lots of precedence of this pattern, for example [`int read() in java.io.Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29)

Comment: Again like UmNyobe's comment... I appreciate your good advices, but I myself can think about this kind of workarounds... Actually everything can be done as an alternative pattern. The question, nevertheless, is not about that.

Comment: no... I'm talking about `int` here, it can represent all chars, then something else, in your case, a sentinel value of "no char". The sentinel value cannot be mistaken for any char 0x0000-0xFFFF. This is a common practice, see javadoc of `Reader.read()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, a `Character` object can be `null`, so it has to take more place in RAM than a regular `char` which cannot be null : in a way, `Character`s are a superset of `char`s.

However, in a given part of your code, the JIT compiler might be able to detect that you `Character` is never null an is always used as a regular `char` and optimize that part so that your `Character` uses no more RAM or execution is no slower. I'm just speculating on this very point, though, I don't know if a JIT can actually perform this precise optimization.